# How to call a mysql function in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

I created a generate_slug function from : 
https://github.com/falcacibar/mysql-routines-collection/blob/master/generate_slug.func.sql

It appears in my functions in phpmyadmin:

[image]

Then I make a simple mysql:

```
update categorie set slug = generate_slug(intitule);
```

and I got an error:

> ## 1305 - FUNCTION tr does not exist

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory: you try to use a non-existent function. Check the list of [MySQL functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/functions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you run only **[generate_slug.func.sql](https://github.com/falcacibar/mysql-routines-collection/blob/master/generate_slug.func.sql)**.

Execute also **[tr.func.sql](https://github.com/falcacibar/mysql-routines-collection/blob/master/tr.func.sql)**
 creation script.

```
SELECT `generate_slug`('áàäâãå');
-- aaaaaa
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9039b/2/0)**</kbd>

---

MySQL does not require dependent functions existence during creation:

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e60d/1/0)**</kbd>

But during execution your function will fail. 
For more info search: `deferred name resolution`.